# Jimp. No matching constructor overloading was found. Please see the docs for how to call the Jimp constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, jimp

I am getting this error when trying to create a Jimp object from a buffer.

The weird thing is, this works consistently when the screenshot is of the full thing but doesn't work at some croppings of the screenshot

ie. when I am inputting a screenshot of various parts of the screen at various sizes and shapes, it either works or doesn't consistently for the size/ratio

```
export function saveScreenshot(screenshot, fileName) {
  let img = screenshot.image
  let width = screenshot.width
  let height = screenshot.height
  let fixedImg = new Uint8Array(img.length); 
  for (let i=0; i < img.length; i+=4) { 
    fixedImg[i] = img[i+2]; // r 
    fixedImg[i+1] = img[i+1]; // g 
    fixedImg[i+2] = img[i+0]; // b 
    fixedImg[i+3] = 255; // a
  }
  new Jimp({data: fixedImg, width: width, height: height}, (err, image) => {
    console.log(err)
    image.resize(DETECTION_WIDTH, DETECTION_HEIGHT).write(fileName);
  });
}
```